# How to expand interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, spfx

I expand my method getNews() and want to return any values (itemsValues - array, feedValues - object).

```
public getNews(): Promise<Array<RssInfo>> {
        const request = `https://api.news.com`;
        return this._ctx.httpClient
            .get(request, HttpClient.configurations.v1)
            .then((resp: HttpClientResponse) => {
                return resp.json();
            }).then((values: any) => {

                const itemsValues = values.items.map((v: any) => {
                    const post: RssInfo = {
                        title: v.title,
                        description: v.description,
                        content: v.content,
                        pubDate: v.pubDate,
                        author: v.author,
                        link: v.link,
                        enclosure: v.enclosure.link,
                    };
                    return post;
                });
                const feedValues = values.feed
                return [itemsValues, feedValues]
            })
    }
```

My RssInfo interface:

```
export default class RssInfo {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    content: string;
    pubDate?: string;
    author: string;
    link: string;
    enclosure?: string;
}
```

And I try to render in my component:
data[0] - this is my array, which I will map;
data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ixbV.png) - this is my object from which I will get values;

```
private loadData(): Promise<Array<RssInfo>> {
    return this.props.service.getNews().then((result: Array<RssInfo>) => {
      return result;
    });
  }

public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.loadData().then(data => {
      
      this.setState({
        items: data[0],
        feedInfo: data[1],
        isLoaded: true,
      });
    }).catch(error => { console.error(error); });
  }
```

But I have the next error
[image: error]
How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like the state is expected to be an array. You could wrap the object in an array (e.g. `[{ items: data[0], feedInfo: data[1], isLoaded: true }]`). Or change the type for the state to match the expected usage.